# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio

i'm trying to load all HTML element's inner text by tag name, this works so far but i want it only to show ones where the OuterHtml contains a certain string, i am using this code below:

```
Public Class web

    Private Sub browse_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles browse.DocumentCompleted
        Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = browse.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

        Form1.o.Text = Form1.o.Text + "Retrieving Members from: " + browse.Url.ToString + "." + vbNewLine

        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In elements

            If (CurElement.InnerHtml.Contains("http://www.programmingguild.com/forum/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=")) Then
                Form1.s = CurElement.InnerText

                Form1.o.Text = Form1.o.Text + Form1.s + vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What line are you getting this on? Which `HtmlElement`? Are you sure all the ones you are iterating over have an `InnerHtml`?

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? Run it in the debugger and make sure you break on that exception.

Comment: sorry guys, bit of a rookie error i used innerhtml instead of outerhtml